# Javascript Keyup isn't called when Command and another is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is Mac only problem; I've tried this on windows and it works fine.**

I have a script that saves which keys are pressed on `keydown` and deletes them on `keyup`.

```
$(function(){
    var keys = [];

    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        keys[event.which] = true;
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        delete keys[event.which];

        console.log(keys);
    });
});
```

All I am doing right now is console logging whatever is left after the keyup, which should be nothing. This works as expected when you press any number of keys simultaneously.

HOWEVER, when you press `command` and any other key, the other key is NOT released! So `console.log` will show that key to be `true`. This will remain `true` until you press that key itself.

This only happens on a Mac, and it only happens when one of the keys pressed is the Command key. Here is a very simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhYUooF8sfhPRqXcmEEZ?) with the above example.

Any ideas?

Comment: Btw, instead of using an Array you could use `var keys = {};` and then `console.log(JSON.stringify(keys));` :)

Comment: @Jack, what's the advantage of that? I want to use an array.

Comment: Why? I can't imagine why the order of elements would make a difference and a sparse array just seems like the wrong data type.

Comment: Actually, the order for the application I am using is crucial! That is the reason why I need an array.

Comment: The ordering won't tell you which key came first, so how are you using an ordering that involves key codes? Not saying you're wrong, I'm just curious.

Comment: @Jack, I using this as part of a script to add keyboard shortcut for my application. For instance, pressing `shift + s` would save something. I use order (of the `event.which`) so that if you press `shift` and then `s` or `s` and then `shift`, it wouldn't make a difference. Does that make sense?

Comment: Fair enough; I'm assuming you have a good reason not to check for `event.shiftKey`? :)

Comment: Haha, I do check for `event.shiftKey`. That was just an example. I mean you are pressing two or more keys, but the order wouldn't matter. Either way, pressing `a + b + c` in any order should result in the same action.

Comment: Just making sure you know what you're doing :D carry on.

Comment: This is not relevant Lol!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mac is modifying your key whenever you press `Command`, and thus the normal `keyup` event never fires.

`C` = command key and `K` = non-command key

As you press `C` and `K`, they register normally.  While they are both simultaneously pressed, the Mac captures `K` and modifies it.  In modifying `K`, the Mac somehow makes `K`'s `keyup` event not fire as it is supposed to.  `C`'s `keyup` works as expected, however.

Since `K`'s `keyup` never actually fires, it won't correctly delete the matching element from `keys`.  Later on when you press `K` without `C`, the `keydown` event overwrites the existing `keydown` in `keys`.  And when `K`'s `keyup` correctly fires, it works as expected.

---

> In addition to all the normal keys used to input ASCII characters,
>   keyboards typically have many special purpose keys that do other
>   things. These do not necessarily generate the same events as normal
>   keys, and they show less consistency across browsers.

[JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).  Potentially helpful article for all `key`-related problems.

Comment: That's very interesting. So I did what you asked. On `keyup`, `K` is never called. Also more interestingly, the event `keypress` is never actually called if `C` is pressed with `K`.

Comment: I know the `keypress` event is finicky even without special keys, so that isn't a surprise.  Is there a `keyup` that happens without a matching `kedown`?  It could be that the mac altogether removes the `keyup` event from the modified `K` instead of trying to emulate some other key.

Comment: Yes, `keydown` happens for both `C` and `K`, but I only getting a matching `keyup` for `C` only.

Comment: Then my theory is mostly correct.  Instead of the Mac creating an unmatched `keyup` event for a different key, it is modifying it so much that the browser isn't picking up a `keyup` at all.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Curse you Apple! *shakes fist*

Comment: There is another possible explanation I just thought of.  I'm wondering if the Mac is making the browser lose focus when you combine `Command` with another `key`, which would result in the events not firing correctly.

Comment: Wait so there is no solution to this problem?? heeeelp

Answer (score 0):

I can't fix this Mac issue, but here is my way of getting around it.

**This answer will help you if you are trying to have keyboard-shortcut behavior**, where the user presses CMD+S to do save, or something like that.  This answer does not apply to people who may be building a game or something where their keyboard's keydown states need to be known at each run frame.  Sorry!

In the KeyboardEvent returned by keydown, you can do the following

```
$(document).keydown(function(keyboardEvent) {

    if (keyboardEvent.metaKey){ 
        // on Mac, CMD is down ...or Meta key is down on pc

        console.log(keyboardEvent.meta + " & command key are down")
        switch (keyboardEvent.which) { 
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

If your keyboard shortcut overlaps with the browser's, you need to make sure to cancel the propagation of the keyboard event,

```
keyboardEvent.preventDefault()
```

I hope this helps people who want keyboard shortcut functionality that is Mac compatible!